# JSon.NET deserialising subitems

Tags: c#, json, json.net

For deserialisation I usually use an object with the same property names as found in the JSon and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Des>(jsonstring)`.
But now I came across this:

```
{
   "id": 0815,
   "name": "whatever"
   "addedInfo": {
       "thisisinteresting": 4711,
       "id_str": "2336"
    }
}
```

How can I tell JSon.Net to pull the 'thisisinteresting' part of the sub category into a class like:

```
class Des
{
   int id;
   string name;
   int thisisinteresting;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial way would be to actually model your class to the JSON structure:

```
public class AddedInfo
{
    public int thisisinteresting { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public AddedInfo addedInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then add a property to the RootObject to emit the property:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public AddedInfo addedInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int thisisinteresting { get { return addedInfo.thisisinteresting; } }
}
```

There are alternatives like creating a custom serializer or using JObject and deserialize the structure yourself, but I won't go into that. If you need to parse the JSON anyway, the price to deserialize it entirely is small.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this as this would clutter my code with many small classes. So it's clutter or a roll-your-own serializer. Anyway: thanks